# Inability to secure any research position after PhD and postdoc. I am stuck with my low prospects research field. How do I proceed with my career?

Tags: career-path, changing-fields

My PhD research was in computational modeling of shot peening process using finite element analysis. An example publication can be found [here](https://www.mdpi.com/2075-4701/8/3/190/htm). I did my PhD and currently pursuing my postdoc in the same Canadian university.

My research was entirely computational. It was not a high impact research nor complex. Nor did I publish in any high impact journal. The highest impact factor journal I could publish in was 3.8.

I have published 8 publications till date (4 First author, 4 co-authored). I can publish many papers on my topic as there's countless parameters to play with and so much physics to learn.

However, all jobs in my field are experimental. I have been searching for jobs (industry and academia) for the past year. I can't find any job in computational modeling. All openings are in experimental work.

I made a mistake in not carrying out any experimental work in my research. I should have thought about future aspects 6 years ago before selecting this field.

Any advice on how to change a career path after PhD and Postdoc? I have to get experimental experience in my repertoire. Also, everyone wants machine learning experience from computational researchers now. I don't have time to gain knowledge in it.

Currently, I am a postdoc with my PhD advisor and I am actively searching for positions elsewhere. However, I am not getting response from any university/industry elsewhere. I seriously need some guidance.

Comment: If you can't turn your skills into a job in the Toronto metro area there is something wrong with how you're looking for or applying to jobs.

Comment: @Libor I am applying to positions but I am not getting any response. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You may wish to look at the workplace.SE; non-research careers are outside of our expertise. I suspect hiring a professional to review your resume and cover letter may be a good investment.

Answer (score 2):

Never look for the job only in computational modelling. Start making a list of your skills:

1. Programming
2. Math
3. Mechanical engg
4. surface treatments

Take all the keywords from your paper. Or list common things that you can relate to industry. Search for these.

And it is not always necessary to always be in research after Postdoc. Even PhD in biology have found their way into programming.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I am decent in programming, objectively bad in maths and fundamentals of mechanical engineering. I am good in modeling surface engineering related research. I don't really know what kind of jobs would be appropriate for me.

Comment: Please look at some professional help at brushing up CV. Start from scratch. Different jobs needs different types of cover letter. Never say 'bad' at math. Everyone has different sets of skills: Perhaps you can use this time to learn DevOps (like system admin). I am sure a lot of small-middle size companies may need some one with eye on partial programming (but maintaining engineering stuff). Look for persons that already have positions that you want (in linkedin or something equiv) and see their skills. Sometimes companies need people with a bit math, a bit modelling a bit .... something.